# Is it possible to inject sql on a numeric only value?

Tags: php, mysql, security

I have this code:

```
“SELECT * FROM colomn_name WHERE id = ‘$id’”
```

Can I know if it is SECURE way to get the id from database?
P.S: I make FILTER_VAR that confirmed the id is numeric.

Comment: You could always escape the `$id` variable. You can accomplish that using the `addslashes()` function. Use this for good pratice, as you will most defenetly have to handle strings in the future. http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php

Comment: *Do not* rely on `addslashes()` to prevent SQL injection. Use prepared statements with bound parameters, always, for every query. [**This post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) has some good examples.

Comment: Please also show the code where you use filter_var and the code you use to access the database? Are you using mysqli or PDO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are worried about sql injection, then yes it is OK. But you need to be absolutely sure that id has only digits in it.
Have a look [here](https://www.netsparker.com/blog/web-security/sql-injection-cheat-sheet/) for many other tips.

Comment: That mean, if I absolutely sure that id it’s only NUMERIC digits it is COMPLETELY SECURED? I am programming a Security System, I want make sure it is secured.

Comment: Then yes. a numeric value without any other characters cannot cause sql injection. It might cause a problem if the number is too big for the delay server to use so you might want to check that as well.

Comment: Thanks so much, please if you know more about this so give me advice. And yes, am gonna to make sure it is not too big.

Comment: I will. Thanks so much. I appreciate your help.

Comment: If you found this answer helpful please mark it as answered.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A more secure way of doing this would be using prepared statements. The reason for this is that while input validation depends on the function used to make sure the input is correct, prepared statements would ensure that the statement and the values cannot be mixed leading to an sql injection. In the past there have been multiple problems with input validation libraries so it's not a completely secure solution. You can take a look [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp) for more information.